# How do I fix Error MSB4018 in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio

> error MSB4018: The "VCMessage" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
>      at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
>      at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
>      at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ResourceUtilities.FormatString(String unformatted, Object[] args)
>      at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TaskLoggingHelper.FormatString(String unformatted, Object[] args)
>      at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TaskLoggingHelper.FormatResourceString(String resourceName, Object[] args)
>      at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TaskLoggingHelper.LogWarningWithCodeFromResources(String messageResourceName, Object[] messageArgs)
>      at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.VCMessage.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult)   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets    990 6   vtk_minimal

Comment: what exactly were you compiling? And did that only happen after you added/edited something?

Comment: an c++ code. actually I installed visual studio. then build vtk library on it. now I'm trying to test it with an example code I found on internet. it does not work. before this, I was trying to handle LNK2019, LNK1120. I thought there's a problem with linker.

Comment: You might be trying too much at once. That code might be old or wrong. Its up to the person who wrote it to help / update.

Comment: I obtained the same issue when building ITK 4.3.1

Comment: If go to the error list window and click on the error you may get more information. In my case it pointed to a line in Microsoft.CppCommon.targets which was an XML element. In the arguments attribute one value was %(Link.ProgramDatabaseFile) which was not set and causing the problem.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem. I had an old Visual Studio 2005 C++ project, which I reopened with Visual Studio 2010 C++. For me, the first suggestion proposed at [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/521318/error-msb4018-the-vcmessage-task-failed-unexpectedly) worked:

> The issue stems from the unexpected $(TargetDir) found in the property page under Link->OutputFile. During the build process, we tried to expand the OutputFile to a fullpath but only got an empty value. Thus, it led to the index out-of-bound exception.
>
> It is unlikely we will be able to fix these before VS2010 release. The workaround is to correct OutputPath or inherit from parent.

Right-click on the project and go to Properties > Linker > General. Then set "Output File" to "<Inherit from parent or project defaults>"

Hope that fixes it for you too.

Comment: Excellent, I changed the Output file path and change it back the way it was, and it started working for all solutions.

Comment: 10 years have passed and as of VS 2019 (didn't test VS 2022), they still have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out what was wrong. The only thing that fixed this error for me was to remove the configuration and create a new one. 
So in Configuration Manager I removed the one that would not build, and I recreated it from a similar one.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but the problem is still actual (at least, in VS 2019).
In my case, it occurred only during the command-line compilation using a cmd script.

The error was caused by the script that set and used TargetPath for own needs to a valid path without a trailing slash. Apparently, this caused confusion in some MSVC tools even while the project (.vcxproj) didn't include any TargetPath references or uses.

Renaming TargetPath to TargetPathBase in my scripts has resolved the problem.