# problems with building in visual studio 2013 can't interpret the error appearing

Tags: c++, msbuild

I am facing for some time now an issue concerning a code I am formulating in VS 2013. I try to build my code in order to get a .dll file, which I can later use to a simulation program to get some results. The point is that the build isn't successful and an error appears, which I don't know how to eliminate. That's why I need your help. The situation is as follows. Several messages appear, all of the same origin, one of which says the following:

> ```
> 1>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1186,5):
> error MSB4018: The "VCMessage" task failed unexpectedly.
> ```

As a matter of fact more errors with the same path appear but with different content each time.

Can you tell me how to fix this? I can't continue with my work, because I have stuck with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in MS Build. I googled the id and found immediately a fix for earlier similar bug, (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/959162), for VS 2008. Perhaps just upgrade to VS 2015, that could help.

Comment: See also (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608319/msbuild-error-msb4018-in-vs2015-the-link-task-failed-unexpectedly)

Comment: And (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121781/how-to-fix-error-msb4018-the-vcmessage-task-failed-unexpectedly-in-visual-s), **etc.**. It seems there are many possible causes, and ditto fixes. Seems impossible to say which applies to your case.

Comment: Thnaks!!! Can you pinpoint for me exactly which XML file do I need to erase from the project, considering that you have read the link you sent me before:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608319/msbuild-error-msb4018-in-vs2015-the-link-task-failed-unexpectedly

Comment: I work with VS 2013 AND I went to

Project Properties->Linker->Debugging->Generate Debug Info

and I set this property as No and then as Optimize for debugging (/DEBUG)

It didn't work for me.

Also in the other similar posts,  you mentioned that an empty XML element exists in the project file, in which file in AAPI or SDK? Which one is it exactly?

Thank you!

Comment: I just reported my immediate google results. I don't know more than that there are a bunch of MSBuild problems that are reported in about the same general way. Maybe you can better diagnostics building from the command line?

Comment: Will do, but until then do you have any idea which is the XML file, that I need to erase? I am new in VS . i have no clue which one is the false one.