# error MSB4018: The “VCMessage” task failed unexpectedly' in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 Professional.
Native C++ project.
After I have changed some of project settings project building ends with this:

```
Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(770,5): error MSB4018: The "VCMessage" task failed unexpectedly.
Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(770,5): error MSB4018: System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(770,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
...
```

PlatformToolSet mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121781/how-to-fix-error-msb4018-the-vcmessage-task-failed-unexpectedly-in-visual-s) is set.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time it is

```
Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Debugging -> Generate Program Database File
```

If the file name is omitted (while the neighbour option "Generate Debug Info" is not "No") then VS-2017 finishes building with the error MSB4018. A target is built in this case nevertheless.

Comment: This was the solution to my problem too. Your answer saved a lot of time for me. Thank you.

Comment: This error could be generated also by incorrect settings in the project creation stage (tested on Visual Studio 2013). Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62918357/936700

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the project and go to Properties > Linker > General. 
Then set "Output File" to "Inherit from parent or project defaults"

Answer (score 0):

Go to the error list window and click on the error and you may get more information. In my case it pointed to a line in Microsoft.CppCommon.targets which was an XML element. In the arguments attribute one value was %(Link.ProgramDatabaseFile) which was not set and causing the problem.